# How to show div depending on the selected checkbox value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

Trying to show div depends on the selected checkbox values. But not working. If i check bus 12 from the checkbox  i want to show bus1 and bus2. Suppose if i uncheck bus 12 i want to hide bus1 and bus2. same for other like Bus34 and Bus56. How to do it?

app.component.ts:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < formValue.checkboxes.length; ++i) {
      const matchedVal1 = formValue.checkboxes[i];
      console.log(matchedVal1);

       if(matchedVal1 =="bus-12"){

        this.bus1 = true;
        this.bus2 = true;

       }else{
        this.bus1 = false;
        this.bus2 = false;
       }

       if(matchedVal1 =="bus-34"){

        this.bus3 = true;
        this.bus4 = true;

      }else{
        this.bus3 = false;
        this.bus4 = false;
      }


      if(matchedVal1 =="bus-56"){
        this.bus5 = true;
        this.bus6 = true;
      }else{
        this.bus5 = false;
        this.bus6 = false;
      } 

    }
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-custom-value-g8wrgu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: a input type check box **only** can to have two value: true or false. So you can not subscribe to the FormArray and give values. You can take the aproach I indicate in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When we want to mannage a series of checkboxes and store in an array the values selected we can use an unique FormControl, **not** a FormArray. then we use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) in the way

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes; let i = index" >
    <input type="checkbox" 
      [ngModel]="checkboxesControl.value?
              checkboxesControl.value.indexOf(checkbox.value)>=0:false" 
      (ngModelChange)="change($event,checkbox.value)"
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
       />{{checkbox.name}}
    <br />
  </ng-container>
```

Where we declare

```
checkboxesControl:FormControl=new FormControl(null)
```

And our function change

```
  change(checked:boolean,value:string)
  {
      const oldValue=this.checkboxesControl.value || []
      let newValue=null;
      if (checked)
        newValue=this.checkboxes.map(x=>x.value)
                 .filter(x=>oldValue.indexOf(x)>=0 || x==value)
      else
        newValue=this.checkboxes.map(x=>x.value)
                    .filter(x=>oldValue.indexOf(x)>=0 && x!=value)

      this.checkboxesControl.setValue(newValue.length?newValue:null)
  }
```

Then you can use the value of the formControl

```
<div *ngIf="checkboxesControl.value && checkboxesControl.value.indexOf('bus-12')>=0">
Bus1
</div>

<div *ngIf="checkboxesControl.value && checkboxesControl.value.indexOf('bus-12')>=0">
Bus2
</div>

<div *ngIf="checkboxesControl.value && checkboxesControl.value.indexOf('bus-34')>=0">
Bus3
</div>

<div *ngIf="checkboxesControl.value && checkboxesControl.value.indexOf('bus-34')>=0">
Bus4
</div>

<div *ngIf="checkboxesControl.value && checkboxesControl.value.indexOf('bus-56')>=0">
Bus5
</div>

<div *ngIf="checkboxesControl.value && checkboxesControl.value.indexOf('bus-56')>=0">
Bus6
</div>
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-custom-value-dxmgdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

when you submit, check the length of checkboxes, if eq 0 hide all,

```
  submit() {
    const checkboxControl = this.checkboxGroup.controls.checkboxes as FormArray;
    const formValue = {
      ...this.checkboxGroup.value,
      checkboxes: checkboxControl.value.filter((value) => !!value),
    };
    this.submittedValue = formValue;
    /// hide if no select
    if(formValue.checkboxes.length == 0){
      alert("no select , hide all");
    }
    console.log(formValue);
```

https://angular-checkbox-custom-value-yfg1m2.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 0):

The problem why the display of bus HTML is not work correctly is due to when every iteration of array, you will update the previous bus value from `true` to `false`.

Example:

Checked: ["bus-12", "bus-34"]

First iteration ("bus-12"):

Result:

```
bus1 = true;
bus2 = true;
```

Second iteration ("bus-34")

You will set `bus1` and `bus2` to `false` as `matchedVal1 != "bus-12"` but `matchedVal1 == "bus-34`.

```
bus1 = false;
bus2 = false;
bus3 = true;
bus4 = true;
```

In short, when you tick multiple checkboxes, the last `bus` group (which is the last ticked checkbox) will only be true.

---

To fix, you can work with array `.includes()` to prevent overwriting for the not relevant value.

```js
if (formValue.checkboxes.includes('bus-12')) {
  this.bus1 = true;
  this.bus2 = true;
} else {
  this.bus1 = false;
  this.bus2 = false;
}

if (formValue.checkboxes.includes('bus-34')) {
  this.bus3 = true;
  this.bus4 = true;
} else {
  this.bus3 = false;
  this.bus4 = false;
}

if (formValue.checkboxes.includes('bus-56')) {
  this.bus5 = true;
  this.bus6 = true;
} else {
  this.bus5 = false;
  this.bus6 = false;
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-custom-value-jbiv6t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I feel it's better use a FormControl that store an array

Answer (score 0):

I'll have something similar and I do it like this

on the ts I'll add this code

```
    get formValues() {
    return this.checkboxGroup.value.checkboxes;
  }
```

so I can get the reference values for the checkbox array.
And then on the html I'll do this

```
<div *ngIf="formValues[0]">Bus1</div>

<div *ngIf="formValues[0]">Bus2</div>

<div *ngIf="formValues[1]">Bus3</div>

<div *ngIf="formValues[1]">Bus4</div>

<div *ngIf="formValues[2]">Bus5</div>

<div *ngIf="formValues[2]">Bus6</div>
```

But this example works without the submit logic. For the submit logic you can add a flag/ boolean variable like for example submitted and it should go like this

```
submit() {
this.submitted = true;
}
```

and only add this to the html

```
<div *ngIf="formValues[0] && submitted">Bus1</div>
```

and update it as best works for you

this is the working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-custom-value-r4zy3l?file=src/app/app.component.ts